Looping through folders to find shapefiles and then merge them
I am trying to merge shapefiles into one shapefile by looping through folders. I merge them one by one by iterating through each file then merging it with an empty gdf that I set with columns that are the same as each polygons attribute table.
I get the error 'MergeError: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'ints_ct_x', 'GIW_x', 'dist_str_m_x', 'hydric_x', 'cwi_cov_x', 'cluster_x', 'touch_x', 'perim_m_x', 'area_m2_x', 'Index_x', 'dist_NN_m_x'} is not allowed.'
"""
Merging Filtered Shapefiles
"""

# Define a Function to filter through the root folder containing the shape files

# Define a Function to filter through the root folder containing the shape files

def merge_shape_files(root_folder_path, ppr_sinks):
    
    # Define the intended suffix to filter for
    shapesuffix = '_nostream.shp'
    
    for shape_folder in os.listdir(root_folder_path):
        
        shape_fl_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path, shape_folder)
        
        if os.path.isdir(shape_fl_path):
            for shape_name in os.listdir(shape_fl_path):
                shape_path = os.path.join(shape_fl_path, shape_name)
                if os.path.isfile(shape_path) and shape_name.endswith(shapesuffix):
                    
                    # Read the Shape file using Geopandas
                    
                    shape_gdf = gpd.read_file(shape_path)
                    
                    # Merge the shapefile to the
                    ppr_sinks = ppr_sinks.merge(shape_gdf, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return ppr_sinks

ppr_columns = ['Index', 'area_m2', 'perim_m', 'cluster', 'touch', 'ints_ct', 'GIW', 'dist_str_m', 'dist_NN_m', 'agr', 'hydric', 'cwi_cov']

ppr_sinks = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=ppr_columns)
merge_shape_files(root_folder_path, ppr_sinks)


Why are you merging with an emtpy dataframe? You mean to concat with axis=0?

By merging I think you mean appending the rows of each shapefile to the rows of the previous shapefiles?
pandas.merge is not meant to do something like that, from the documentation:
Merge DataFrame or named Series objects with a database-style join.

So for each shapefile, it will (try to) add all columns again to the GeoDataFrame.
For your needs, check out pandas.concat.
Minimal sample code:
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    [{"name": "L-shape", "geometry": shapely.Point(0, 1)}], crs="epsg:31370"
)
gdf2 = gdf1
gdf = pd.concat([gdf1, gdf2])

# Print some information to show/validate the result
print(f"{type(gdf)=}")
# type(gdf)=<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
print(f"{gdf.crs.to_epsg()=}")
# gdf.crs.to_epsg()=31370
print(gdf)
#       name             geometry
# 0  L-shape  POINT (0.000 1.000)
# 0  L-shape  POINT (0.000 1.000)


Makes sense, I think I tried that and it still did not want to work. I will try again though, maybe I was missing something.

When I replace it with append I get the error ''GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'pd'

Oops, indeed, append apparently isn't available on a GeoDataFrame. pd.concat() does the trick though: I added some sample code.
